# Solution for no response on server

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-16.04, ufw

So recently i asked a question to digital ocean, and the question goes like this. "I followed the steps to set up nginx ubuntu my redis mongodb pm2 the web application seems to be running but when i hit my ip address there was no response at all. the request to the ip address [myipadddress] was not received by my application. i checked that i set up the etc/nginx/sites-available as well, could you point out where i did wrong ?"

also i sent them the test i did, and the test i did goes like this.

```
$ curl -x http://[my ip address]:80 --trace-ascii /tmp/dump.txt 
https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub -o /tmp/key.pub
% Total % Received % Xferd Average Speed Time Time Time Current
Dload Upload Total Spent Left Speed
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 --:--:-- 0:01:00 --:--:-- 0
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
mycomputername ~/code/freelance/exmapleproj/exampleproj on EB-717- 
notification-backend[!?$]
$ cat /tmp/dump.txt
== Info: Trying [my ip address]...
== Info: TCP_NODELAY set
== Info: Connected to [my ip address] (my ip address) port 80 (#0)
== Info: Establish HTTP proxy tunnel to dl-ssl.google.com:443
=> Send header, 126 bytes (0x7e)
0000: CONNECT dl-ssl.google.com:443 HTTP/1.1
0028: Host: dl-ssl.google.com:443
0045: User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
005e: Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
007c:
== Info: Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
== Info: Received HTTP code 0 from proxy after CONNECT
== Info: Closing connection 0
```

Answer (score 0):

now it works , by allowing the sudo ufw allow 80/tcp , and sudo ufw allow 6379/tcp. Are there better answers ?

also i asked another question within my same ticket to digital ocean.

```
BUT how can i set my mongod and redis to listen to 0.0.0.0:27017 & 
0.0.0.0:63719 instead of 

tcp 0 0 127.0.0.1:27017 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 1368/mongod
tcp 0 0 127.0.0.1:6379 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 1362/redis-server 1

AND 

ALSO, how come the redis-server that i set up is not listening on tcp6         
?
```

their answers were like this :

In this case, both instances are based on the configurations which may be taking defaults depending on the installation package source. You can review these details here:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#net-options

https://redis.io/topics/config

***You will want to ensure that configuration for binding to all address is supported and enabled for the instances and that any default values of localhost are updated.***

Can someone explain to me what and point me a direction for the bold and italic statement ? Also, i still can't find the document to get redis to listen on tcp6. sorry new in setting up a server